# c# mvc ajax post 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I'm trying ajax post but getting internal server error.My action:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult MezunGetir(string skip)
{
}
```

Ajax post:

```
$.post("/Home/MezunGetir", {skip:cekilenOgrenci}, function(result){});
```

Error:

> POST http://example.net/Home/MezunGetir 500 (Internal Server Error)

I tried another solutions on stackoverflow but not worked. How i can do it?

Comment: what are you returning from action?

Comment: How are you setting "cekilenOgrenci" Does this have a value before you post. Perhaps put an alert on it to see the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**500 Internal Server Error**](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938) means that some exception or run-time error has occurred in the controller action at server side which was not handled properly, just put a break-point and debug the controller action to see where it is breaking.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried on local its worked but not working on prod server. Why does this happen?

Comment: there can be many reasons, configuration differences, connection string differences, or might be some other reason